# How to get data according to Index Number in vue Js from Api?

Tags: api, vue.js, indexing

Q1. How to get data according to Index Number in Vue Js from API?

Q2. And when I put `{{item.title}}` it shows an error that the title is undefined ...How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in alot of ways

1. you can have your index and get it like this

let `obj = Arr[index]`

2. if its a function you can set it like this

   @click="getCurrentObj(item <= which you are using in v-for)

and in methods

```
getCurrentObj(item)
{
this.selectedObj = item
}
```

you can explain more exactly what you are looking for so i can help you better.